# How do you organise your NInject modules?

Tags: module, ninject

NInject's module architecture seems useful but I'm worried that it is going to get in a bit of a mess.

How do you organise your modules? Which assembly do you keep them in and how do you decide what wirings go in which module?

Comment: Good question. I would like to see more discussion of this as I share your concerns. Having one module per subsystem sounds reasonable, but I also have modules for wiring up dependencies differently for Unit Testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each subsystem gets a module. Of course the definition of what warrants categorisation as a 'subsystem' depends...

In some cases, responsibility for some bindings gets pushed up to a higher level as a lower-level subsystem/component is not in a position to make a final authoritative decision - in some cases this can be achieved by passing parameters into the Module.

Answer (score 2):

Replying to my own post after a couple of years of using NInject.

Here is how I organise my NInjectModules, using a Book Store as an example:

- BookStoreSolution

  - Domain.csproj
  - Services.csproj

    - CustomerServicesInjectionModule.cs
    - PaymentProcessingInjectionModule.cs
  - DataAccess.csproj

    - CustomerDatabaseInjectionModule.cs
    - BookDatabaseInjectionModule.cs
  - CustomSecurityFramework.csproj

    - CustomSecurityFrameworkInjectionModule.cs
  - PublicWebsite.csproj

    - PublicWebsiteInjectionModule.cs
  - Intranet.csproj

    - IntranetInjectionModule.cs

What this is saying is that each project in the system comes prepackaged with one or more NInject modules that know how to setup the bindings for that project's classes.

Most of the time an individual application is not going to want to make significant changes to the default injection modules provided by a project. For example, if I am creating a little WinForm app which needs to import the DataAccess project, normally I am also going to want to have all the project's Repository<> classes bound to their associated IRepository<> interfaces.

At the same time, there is nothing forcing an individual application to use a particular injection module. An application can create its own injection module and ignore the default modules provided by a project that it is importing. In this way the system still remains flexible and decoupled.

Comment: So...this means you have to include a Ninject package/reference into each of the projects that have a module??? I would prefer to have one single place in my caller assembly (e.g., the web project) where I register every service I need, and then only that assembly will take a direct reference to Ninject.  Thoughts?

Comment: Yes that is a disadvantage with this setup. However unless you have a very pure application that never uses property injection or uses Kernel.Get<>() then I usually end up with an NInject reference anyway.

Comment: well...i just finished a project that used Unity for DI, and I ended up with one long RegisterServices method in my bootstrapper within the web project.  None one my class libs projects had a direct dependency on Unity or EntLib directly.  They all leveraged constructor injection.  I thought it was rather nice.

Comment: Yes it is nice to work on a greenfields project, so you can do everything properly. A few questions though - what would you do if you needed to create a Windows application that used the domain layer, service layer etc? Would you duplicate all of the RegisterService method? What if you had another WebSecurity project that only applied to web projects, and you didn't want to import it into your Windows app? How would you organise the registration of services for this web-only project? It is at this point that we need modules and we need to keep them somewhere that they can be shared.