# Using NinjectModules from Service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject

I fail to understand how to probably setup my Ninject IoC container. 
I have a Service layer which contains implementations of several services and implementation of my `DbContext` and ASP.NET Identity like so:

```
public class IdentityModule : NinjectModule
{
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IUserStore<User, int>>().To<UserService>().InSingletonScope();
            Bind<UserManager<User, int>>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

            Bind<IRoleStore<UserRole, int>>().To<UserRoleService>().InSingletonScope();
            Bind<RoleManager<UserRole, int>>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        }
}

public class EntityFrameworkModule : NinjectModule
{
       public override void Load()
       {
           Bind<EntityDbContext>().ToSelf();
           Bind<ICreateDbModel>().To<DefaultDbModelCreator>();
           Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<EntityDbContext>();
           Bind<IWriteEntities>().To<EntityDbContext>();
           Bind<IReadEntities>().To<EntityDbContext>();
       }
}
```

These are loaded into my `NinjectWebCommen` (MVC layer):

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    var modules = new INinjectModule[]
                      {
                         new EntityFrameworkModule(),
                         new IdentityModule()
                      };

    kernel.Load(modules);
}
```

Now my question is:

My `EntityDbContext` should be request scoped, but I am unable to set `.InRequestScope()` from my service layer. Should this `INinjectModule` then be moved to the MVC layer instead of lying in the service layer or should I reference `Ninject.Web.Common` in my service layer? This just seem to be a wrong way since the service layer is not a web-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This place where you wire everything together is called the
>   Composition Root in DI terminology

One of the suggestions is to create a bootstrap for all layers. Check this SO:

[Where to locate Ninject modules in a multi-tier application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985452/where-to-locate-ninject-modules-in-a-multi-tier-application)

Comment: OK, so I should wire the entity framework module up in MVC expect the ones that does not need a request scope.

Comment: That's one way. Personally, I wire everything together in MVC layer. Other suggestion (not related to your question) is to use Ninject.Extensions.Conventions to do binding automatically. This way when I introduce a new service, I don't have to add it to the module.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer but I have been having the same problem. First, make sure Ninject and Ninject.Web.Common are referenced in the service layer, and that you have a using statement for Ninject.Web.Common in your module class.

I couldn't find InRequestScope in Intellisense. I tried a few times opening and closing the project, and it finally showed up. Didn't do anything but close and re-open Visual Studio and it started working.

Comment: I believe its wrong to add UI (web) dependency on my service layer. So I ended up wiring the request scoped stores and classes from my UI (web) layer. No sure if I am doing it correct tho. :)

Comment: I have a three layer solution -- a Web project, a Service project and a Repository project. There is a Ninject Binding Module in each project. I don't think it's a matter of dependencies. It's just where the modules are stored. The binding actually occurs in Global.asax or App_Start.

Comment: Is it fine to reference `Ninject.Web.Common` in a non-web layer?